# OLS in Python: dimension of estimated coefficient matrix is not OK

Tags: python, numpy

I have written a Python code to estimate the parameter from (univariate) linear regression model, but the dimension of the estimated coefficient matrix is not ok. The dimension of vector 'beta_estimated' (reported below) should be (1-by-1) but is (n-by-n). Any thougths?

```
# Linear regression in Python (univariate)
import numpy as np     
import scipy as sci     

x_original  =  np.random.normal(1,1, 100)    
x = np.array([x_original])    
#x_transpose  = x.T                 
beta = [5]  

y_original = (beta * x) + np.random.normal(0, 10, 100)    
y = np.array(y_original)    
#y_transpos = y.T     
product1 = np.dot(x.T, x)    
product2 = np.dot(x.T, y )    
Minv = np.linalg.inv(product1)    
beta_estimated =  np.dot(Minv, product2)
```

Comment: Both `x` and `y` in your example are 2D arrays. Are they supposed to be 2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but if I had to guess the product is the reason why you don't have the dimensions you are looking for. In your case:

```
x   # has a shape of (1, 100)
x.T # has a shape of (100, 1)

np.dot(x.T, x) # produces an array with shape (100, 100)
np.dot(x, x.T) # would produce an array with a shape of (1, 1)
```

So if I think you should reverse the arguments in both of your dot products `np.dot()`. Your code should become:

```
product1 = np.dot(x, x.T)    
product2 = np.dot(y, x.T)
```